# Hot code deploy in intellij with websphere

Tags: intellij-idea, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I am trying to accomplish the same in Intellij as in Eclipse, but I can't get it to work. If I use Eclipse with the Websphere plugins, I can change code anytime without having to manually redeploy or restart the server (websphere liberty).

In Intellij I followed the guidelines, such that I have an exploded webapp linked to websphere. Everything works fine except for the hot deployment. Whenever I change a simple line (e.g. a statement in a servlet) I have to manually press the redeployment button so that the server picks it up. My aim is to have code changes reflect immediately in my website without having to trigger anything manually. How?

Comment: What version of IntelliJ are you using? What edition (Community or Ultimate) are you using? Re this: "In Intellij I followed the guidelines" ... what guidelines? Do you have a link to them?

Comment: Intellij Ultimate 2017.2.4. I basically followed the procedure as defined here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-websphere-server.html#d17085e2045

Comment: And presumably you followed the instructions under "On 'Update' action" ...

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html.

Comment: Ok, I played around with various options. I got a somewhat working situation by activating and setting the 'On frame deactivation' to 'Update Classes and Resources'. However, it essentially stops and restarts the webapp which takes about 2-3 seconds. I wish this were just instant, but at least I'm avoiding manual steps now.

Comment: Could you post your configuration please? I mean the complete one as it could be useful to other people

Comment: submitted a request here on intellij support: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/3365066